# Smalltalk columnar class browser for java development

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, browser, smalltalk

I'd like to develop in Java on Eclipse with the same "Five-panel" class browser than I had in Smalltalk. Is there an eclipse plugin that does it ? I can't find it.

Something like 1st column package names, 2nd column Class names, 3rd column method names and lastly a bottom panel to edit methods.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrange the "packages", "types" and "members" views of the "java browsing" category to have the same layout.

The main difference is that you'll be able, using the scrollbar, to see other members without having to click in the "members" view (I'm not sure about what it did in Smalltalk V or 80... this is so old...).

I have a very similar layout as I put at the left of my screen the views "projects", "packages" and "types" in a column (no place for "members" on my small screen).

Comment: Ok thank you it works. It looks like the browser I have on Pharo. But I can't access to webcontent and all non java files on my j2ee project, whereas I can in smalltalk web framework like seaside. It may be because in seaside everything is smalltalk whereas j2ee not everything is in java, but there are jsp, js, ...

Comment: You can edit a lot of file types, some with plugins. But honestly I prefer to do only java/jsp/properties in Eclipse as it's not the fastest beast...

Comment: What do you use instead of eclipse ?

Comment: It depends on the type of files. Dedicated ones (for svg, png, etc.) or geany for text-like files (or notepad++ when on windows). But I'm using Eclipse for java.

Comment: Ok. I have to use eclipse for work unfortunatly :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

There is no plugin necessary: Select "Window" > "Open perspective..." > "Java Browsing" and you will get something very similar to the original Smalltalk browser. The similarity of this browse perspective likely stems from the origin of the Eclipse IDE: IBM Visual Age for Java/Smalltalk.

Answer (score 0):

This is spanish, but it may help: http://nicopaez.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/smalltalkizando-eclipse/